# CD command is not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am unable to change directory to a path stored as a variable value.

```
cd %VBOX_INSTALL_PATH%
```

If I input the command at the `cmd.exe` prompt it's working, but the same is not working in a batch file.

It's printed as:

> > cd C:Oracle/vbox
> >     C:Oracle/vbox Not a valid directory path

Kindly help me to resolve it.

Comment: It's probably not the `CD` command which isn't working; it's more likely an incorrect or non existant location. It would also have helped were we to have seen the expanded value of `%VBOX_INSTALL_PATH%` and better still how its value was created because it clearly has a missing backslash?

Answer (score 1):

The `CD` command looks like this: `CD C:\Oracle\vbox` So if the error message is `cd C:Oracle/vbox;C:Oracle/vbox Not a valid directory path Kindly help me to resolve it.` I assume the content of `%VBOX_INSTALL_PATH%` is not `C:\Oracle\vbox` but something else. There is at least a `\` missing right after `C:`. Further, this will only work as you expect if you are already on drive C:. If you want the command to work from everywhere, you should add the `/D` parameter:

```
SET "VBOX_INSTALL_PATH"="C:\Oracle\vbox"
CD /D %VBOX_INSTALL_PATH%
```

And by the way, `/` is the regular path separator for **LINUX**. For **Windows**, it is `\`. Windows will often accept `/` but in some cases, it might cause trouble.